# Postfix client configuration problem

Tags: linux, email, postfix

I'm having an issue with a postfix relay, or more accurately a postfix client configuration.

I have a postfix relay that works just fine and 2 machines that uses that relay to send mail through an external server. One of the two machines successfully sends mail through the relay but the second one doesn't and i can't figure out why. I'm not a pro with postfix so please feel free to share your knowledge on the subject.

Machine that works is in SLE12 SP5, machine that doesn't works is in OpenSUSE Leap 15.3.

Both use postfix to send mail

They have the same /etc/postfix/main.cf file (i tried to copy paste it so it really is the same apart from the hostname)

They are on the same subnet so it's not a network problem, i have opened port 25 with iptables on input and ouput on the not working machine

There is no authentication to access the relay or the external mail server (it might change in the future but right now, no authentication required)

Maybe i'm missing something like really obvious but i don't have that kind of knowledge, help please !

Comment: If it doesn't work, you normally get some error messages. Please include them in your question. Analysing a problem that's only described as "doesn't work" isn't really possible.

Comment: Check the ´main.cf` of the server that's denying, you need to add the IPs of the sending servers to `relay_hosts`/`my_networks`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to the people that answered and i'm sorry i didn't gave enough details.

Turns out i was editing the `/etc/postfix/maps/access_client` file without using the `postmap` command everytime. I feel really dumb but at least i learned from it.

Thank you everyone.